# Not discovering services after connection in some android mobile

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux, bluez, pybluez

I'm trying to use Android's Bluetooth Low Energy[BLE supported Android] to communicate with a BLE device. After connect with device, it will not be able to discover the services.
In few mobile phones like samsung galaxy s6,iphone,ipad service are discover and visible.
i don't know, why its working on some mobiles?

For BLE, I use BLUEZ5 stack on my Raspberry pi 3 Device, For running gatt server i used example-gatt-server.py in my board(server) and used mobile for central device(client side)

I use following link for example-gatt-server.py : https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/bluez/blob/master/test/example-gatt-server

And for advertising and start blutooth daemon i used following command

```
$ /usr/lib/bluez5/bluetooth/bluetoothd  -dE &

$ hciconfig hci0 up 

$ hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 15 02 01 1a 11 07 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49  4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

$ hciconfig hci0 leadv 0

$ python example-gatt-server &
```

Comment: You need to add some code for what you are doing - it should also be a reproducible issue so other people can help you. As it is your question will end up getting closed.

Comment: @Blundell thanks man for help